# Shutdown -i access denied

Tags: group-policy

I am looking to do a simple shutdown of a computer in my dorm room. I am under a schools server and I get access denied when trying to remote shutdown with an IP address. Is there a way to bypass this or do I have to be an acceptance in the group policy to perform this action?

I have the IP address and the computer name if that helps any!

Comment: What do you mean by "under a schools server"? Are you logged in to it?

Comment: Why not ssh into it and do a `shutdown now` or `halt`?

Comment: Im not on their domain but I am connected to their WiFi where they push out specific group policies.

Comment: Which operating system is the computer running which you are trying to shutdown remotely? Assuming you mentioned Group Policy, it mostly sounds to be Windows. Try using PSTools, that may help.

Comment: How exactly are you "trying to remote shutdown with an IP address"?

Answer (score 0):

Found this on [sevenforums.com](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/138449-remote-shutdown-other-pc-access-denied-please-help.html)

> The way that I got it to work was to activate the true administrator on each computer....
>
> Per Computer, Elevate the Dos Command Prompt...
>
> type: net user administrator /active:yes
>
> Deactivate admin: net user administrator /active:no
>
> Reboot computer, log into the admin account and set your password by hitting ALT CTRL DEL
>
> Once complete on all computers. Try the Shut down command.